# Non-invocable member "HomeController.ServicesList" cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, .net, razor, ienumerable, ienumerator

I want to take the service information from Cshtml . But I get the error .

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ServiceController[] Services;
            Services = ServiceController.GetServices();

            ServicesViewModel servicesViewModel = new ServicesViewModel();
            ServisModel servisler = new ServisModel();
            List<ServicesViewModel> list = new List<ServicesViewModel>();

            foreach (ServiceController svc in Services)
                {                
                    servicesViewModel.ServiceName = svc.ServiceName;
                    servicesViewModel.ServiceDisplayName = svc.DisplayName;
                    servicesViewModel.ServiceStatus = svc.Status;
                    list.Add(servicesViewModel);
            }            

            return View(ServicesList(list));            
        }



        public class ServicesList : IEnumerable
        {
            List<ServicesViewModel> liste = new List<ServicesViewModel>();             

            public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
            {
                return new MyEnumerator(liste);
            }
        }
```

Error:  CS1955  Non-invocable member 'HomeController.ServicesList' cannot be used like a method.

This is the class MyEnumerator:

```
public class MyEnumerator : IEnumerator
    {
        List<ServicesViewModel> lst = new List<ServicesViewModel>();
        int CurrentLocation = -1;

        public MyEnumerator(List<ServicesViewModel> p) {
            this.lst = p;
        }


        public object Current
        {
            get
            {
                return this.lst[CurrentLocation];
            }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            CurrentLocation++;
            return (CurrentLocation < this.lst.Count);
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            CurrentLocation = -1;
        }
    }
```

And finally this is the cshtml file:

```
@model IEnumerable<ExampleProject.ViewModel.ServicesViewModel> 
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Sunucu Yönetim Paneli | Ana Sayfa";
    ViewBag.Description = "Sunucu Yönetim Paneli";
    ViewBag.Keywords = "sunucu, yönetim,paneli";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Ara", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        Aranacak Kelime: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
        <input type="submit" value="Ara" />
    </p>
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
           Servis Adı
        </th>
        <th>
            Servis Açıklaması
        </th>
        <th>
            Servis Durumu
        </th>
        <th>
            Servis Başlangıç Türü
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.ServiceName
            @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.allServices)*@
        </td>
        <td>
            @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ServiceDisplayName)*@
        </td>
        <td>
            @*@Model.ServiceStatus*@
            @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ServiceDisplayName)*@
        </td>
        <td>
            @*@Model.ServiceStartMode*@
            @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ServiceDisplayName)*@
        </td>
        <td>
            @*@Html.ActionLink("Başlat", "ServiceStart", "ServicesStartStop", new { @id = item.ServiceName }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Durdur", "ServiceStop", "ServicesStartStop", new { @id = item.ServiceName }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("", "", "Başlatma Türü", new { @id = item.ServiceName }, null)*@
            @*<input type="submit" value="Başlat" />
            <input type="submit" value="Durdur" />
            <input type="submit" value="Başlatma Türü" />*@
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: What do you try to do with `ServicesList(list)`? Did you mean `new ServicesList(list)` (which however does not work)? What is it `MyEnumerator`?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyEnumerator : IEnumerator
        {
            List<ServicesViewModel> lst = new List<ServicesViewModel>();
            int CurrentLocation = -1;

            public MyEnumerator(List<ServicesViewModel> p) {
                this.lst = p;
            }


            public object Current
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.lst[CurrentLocation];
                }
            }

            public bool MoveNext()
            {
                CurrentLocation++;
                return (CurrentLocation < this.lst.Count);
            }

            public void Reset()
            {
                CurrentLocation = -1;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 My Cshtml Class.   


 @model IEnumerable<ExampleProject.ViewModel.ServicesViewModel> 
    @{
        Layout = "~/Views/shared/_Layout.cshtml";
        ViewBag.Title = "Sunucu Yönetim Paneli | Ana Sayfa";
        ViewBag.Description = "Sunucu Yönetim Paneli";
        ViewBag.Keywords = "sunucu, yönetim,paneli";
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Ara", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <p>
            Aranacak Kelime: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
            <input type="submit" value="Ara" />
        </p>
    }

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
               Servis Adı
            </th>
            <th>
                Servis Açıklaması
            </th>
            <th>
                Servis Durumu
            </th>
            <th>
                Servis Başlangıç Türü
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.ServiceName
                @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.allServices)*@
            </td>
            <td>
                @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ServiceDisplayName)*@
            </td>
            <td>
                @*@Model.ServiceStatus*@
                @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ServiceDisplayName)*@
            </td>
            <td>
                @*@Model.ServiceStartMode*@
                @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ServiceDisplayName)*@
            </td>
            <td>
                @*@Html.ActionLink("Başlat", "ServiceStart", "ServicesStartStop", new { @id = item.ServiceName }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Durdur", "ServiceStop", "ServicesStartStop", new { @id = item.ServiceName }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("", "", "Başlatma Türü", new { @id = item.ServiceName }, null)*@
                @*<input type="submit" value="Başlat" />
                <input type="submit" value="Durdur" />
                <input type="submit" value="Başlatma Türü" />*@
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, first error: you try to use `ServicesList` like a method but it is a class so you need the new keyword before class name.
Second error: in your `ServicesList` class you don't have a constructor with list as parameters.

To solve the problem you need to change your code in this way:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ServiceController[] Services;
        Services = ServiceController.GetServices();

        ServisModel servisler = new ServisModel();
        List<ServicesViewModel> list = new List<ServicesViewModel>();

        foreach (ServiceController svc in Services)
        {                
            ServicesViewModel servicesViewModel = new ServicesViewModel();
            servicesViewModel.ServiceName = svc.ServiceName;
            servicesViewModel.ServiceDisplayName = svc.DisplayName;
            servicesViewModel.ServiceStatus = svc.Status;
            list.Add(servicesViewModel);
        }            

        return View(new ServicesList(list));            
    }

    public class ServicesList : IEnumerable
    {
        private List<ServicesViewModel> liste = new List<ServicesViewModel>();

        public ServicesList(List<ServicesViewModel> l) {
            liste = l;
        }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new MyEnumerator(liste);
        }
    }
```

Then in your view (cshtml) file you need to change model type from:

```
@model IEnumerable<ExampleProject.ViewModel.ServicesViewModel>
```

To:

```
@model IEnumerable<ExampleProject.[PartThatIDontKnow].ServicesList>
```

And to solve the issues relative to this change like:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

That become:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.GetEnumerator())
```

I realy don't understand what you try to do but in this way the code should be build and run without problems. In your cshtml file I can't see any part of code that try to use `ServicesList`. I hope to be a help. Let me know if all works fine.

Note: when you need to add informations to your question use edit (is under the text of your question) instead of write an answer. I updated your question for you.

Comment: First of all , thank you very much. My English is not very good. I'm sorry for that. I changed code. But have error:       Error:System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ExampleProject.Controllers.HomeController+ServicesList', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ExampleProject.ViewModel.ServicesViewModel]'.

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, sorry! My fault. I edited my answer while you tried my solution. You need to change model type in your view. See my answer after `HomeController` code.

Comment: @model IEnumerable<ExampleProject.[PartThatIDontKnow].ServicesList>         PartThatIDontKnow? I'm ServisModel in IEnumerable<ServicesViewModel> Serviceslist but my error:                                             Error CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<ExampleProject.ViewModel.ServisModel>' because 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<ExampleProject.ViewModel.ServisModel>' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: This error is in cshtml's foreach? If yes why you use ServisModel instead of ServicesList in your view? Another thing that I see just now; the foreach in HomeController it's wrong because in second step you change values for servicesViewModel that will change also the values already in the list because have the same reference. I will update the answer